# Ubuntu Samba ssh login changes after successful login

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, samba

We have many Ubuntu servers running different flavors, but on some of our 14.04 versions we are having a baffling issue with ssh logons.

When a user uses ssh to connect, they are prompted for their password as expected:

```
awesome:~ parrs$ ssh sftp
parrs@sftp's password:
```

After authenticating the username changes to a different username, often in a different domain that the original logon:

```
STUDENT+<redacted>@sftp:~$
```

In those examples we are using Active Directory, and have a main domain that my user `parrs` is a user in, and a sub-domain `student` that all our student accounts are housed in. Where it has  is an actual student account from that domain.

When the Ubuntu server is first joined this issue isn't there, it shows up after some time. In this case it was overnight.

Here is my smb.conf:

```
[global]
     workgroup = <primary domain shortname>
     server string = Samba Server Version %v
     security = ads
     realm = <primary domain>
     password server = <primary domain controller>
     domain master = no
     local master = no
     preferred master = no
     idmap backend = tdb
     idmap uid = 10000-99999
     idmap gid = 10000-99999
     idmap config NSULA:backend = rid
     idmap config NSULA:range = 10000-99999
     winbind separator = +
     winbind enum users = yes
     winbind enum groups = yes
     winbind use default domain = yes
     winbind nested groups = yes
     winbind refresh tickets = yes
     template homedir = /home/%D/%U
     template shell = /bin/bash
     client use spnego = yes
     client ntlmv2 auth = yes
     encrypt passwords = yes
     restrict anonymous = 2
     log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
     max log size = 50
```

This doesn't occur with all the 14.04 machine, only ones deployed later, but we aren't 100% sure of the date. So it must have something to do with a specific update to samba.

As an additional step we removed a server from the domain with `net ads leave -U <username>` which worked successfully. The computer account was removed from our AD. We then re-joined it, and the issue persisted.

Research hasn't found anything that would help resolve this. Any ideas?

Or let me know any other files or troubleshooting information I can supply to help.